# What ciphers are supported for spark internode communication?

Tags: apache-spark, aes

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.2/security.html#encryption

> Property name: `spark.network.crypto.config.*` 
> Default: `None` 
> Meaning: Configuration values for the
> `commons-crypto` library, such as which cipher implementations to use.
> The config name should be the name of commons-crypto configuration
> without the `commons.crypto` prefix.

This description is superficial.

What will happen in case of None?
What ciphers are supported?

Comment: Probably the defaults would depend on your JVM's built-in crypto provider (Sun, SunJCE, etc. or OpenSSL). For the list of config keys - https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-crypto/apidocs/